# on clicking a4j:commandbutton, method does not get executed

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am developing an application using jsf2.0, richfaces 4.0, tomcat 6.0. On a page I am trying to delete a row . But when I click the delete icon, sometimes popup panel does not appear and when it is shown , nothing happens on clicking the delete button.

Following is my .xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<ui:composition template="template.xhtml"> 
     <ui:define name="metadata">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="meetingId" required="true" value="#{meetingBean.selectedMeetId}" />
        </f:metadata>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
    <h3>List of Employees in selected meeting</h3>
    <a4j:status onstart="#{rich:component('statPane')}.show()"
        onstop="#{rich:component('statPane')}.hide()" />
    <h:form>
        <c:if test="#{! empty meetingBean.selectedMeeting}">
            <c:set target="#{flash}" property="selectedMeeting" 
                value="#{meetingBean.selectedMeeting}" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="#{! empty flash.selectedMeeting}">
            <c:set target="#{meetingBean}" property="selectedMeeting"
                value="#{flash.selectedMeeting}" />
        </c:if>
        <rich:extendedDataTable value="#{meetingBean.selectedMeeting.employees}" var="empMeet" border="1" id="table">
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Employee Id</f:facet>
                    #{empMeet.empId}
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header"> Employee Name</f:facet>
                    #{empMeet.firstName} #{empMeet.lastName}
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <a4j:commandLink execute="@this" render="@none" oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmPanel')}.show();">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/icons/delete.gif" alt="delete" />
                    <a4j:param value="#{empMeet.empId}" assignTo="#{meetingBean.deleteEmpId}" />
                </a4j:commandLink>
            </rich:column>
        </rich:extendedDataTable>


        <a4j:jsFunction name="removeEmp" action="#{meetingBean.deleteEmployee}" render="table" execute="@this"
                     oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmPanel')}.hide();" >
        </a4j:jsFunction>


        <rich:popupPanel id="statPane" autosized="true">
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/ai.gif" />
                Please wait...
        </rich:popupPanel>

        <rich:popupPanel id="confirmPanel" autosized="true" >
            Are you sure you want to delete the row? 
            <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide(); return false;" />
            <a4j:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="removeEmp(); return false;" />
        </rich:popupPanel>

            <h:commandButton action="addEmpMeeting" value="Invite More Employees" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

Following is my bean class:

```
package com.drishti.apps.mommanager.meeting;

/**
 * this class represents a meeting object
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

import org.richfaces.component.SortOrder;

import com.drishti.apps.mommanager.employee.AbstractBacking;
import com.drishti.apps.mommanager.employee.EmployeeEntity;
import com.drishti.apps.mommanager.employee.EmployeeService;

@ManagedBean
public class MeetingBean extends AbstractBacking {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{requestScope}")
    private Map<String, Object> requestMap;

    private int meetingId;
    private Date meetingTime;
    private String agenda;
    private String result;
    public String[] empIdsInMeeting;
    private List<EmployeeEntity> employees = new ArrayList<EmployeeEntity>();
    private Integer selectedMeetId;
    private MeetingEntity selectedMeeting;
    private String selectedAgenda;
    private int deleteEmpId;
    private EmployeeEntity deletableEmployee;


    /**
     * this method is used to load a meeting object when it is being updated
     * 
     * @param cse
     */
    public void loadMeeting(ComponentSystemEvent cse) {
        if (null == getSelectedMeeting()) {
            Integer meetId = getSelectedMeetId();
            if (meetId == null) {
                meetId = (Integer)getFlash().get("selectedMeetId");
            }
            if (meetId == null) {
                getFacesContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("The meeting is invalid"));
                getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
                getFacesContext().getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
                        .handleNavigation(getFacesContext(), null, "listMeetings");
            } else {
                MeetingEntity meet = MeetingService.getCurrentInstance().getMeetingForId(meetId);
                if (meet == null) {
                    getFacesContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("The meeting is invalid"));
                    getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
                    getFacesContext().getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
                            .handleNavigation(getFacesContext(), null, "listMeetings");
                } else {
                    getFlash().put("selectedMeeting", meet);
                    getSelectedMeeting();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * this method updates a meeting object
     * 
     * @return
     */

    public void updateMeeting() {
        //String result = null;
        MeetingService meetSer = MeetingService.getCurrentInstance();
        MeetingEntity meeting = getSelectedMeeting();
        meetSer.updateMeeting(meeting);
        getFlash().clear();
        //result = "meetUpdated";
        //return result;
    }

    /**
     * this method adds a meeting object to database
     * 
     * @return
     */

    public void addMeeting() {
        MeetingEntity meeting = (MeetingEntity)getRequestMap().get("meetingEntity");
        MeetingService.getCurrentInstance().addMeeting(meeting);
        //return "successMeeting";
    }

    /**
     * this method is used to delete a meeting
     */
    public void deleteMeeting(){
        MeetingService meetSer = MeetingService.getCurrentInstance();
        MeetingEntity meeting = getSelectedMeeting();
        meetSer.deleteMeeting(meeting);
        getFlash().clear();
    }

    /**
     * returns data model containing all meetings present in database
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public DataModel<MeetingEntity> getMeetingList() {
        DataModel<MeetingEntity> meetingList = new ListDataModel<MeetingEntity>(MeetingService.getCurrentInstance()
                .getMeetings());
        return meetingList;
    }

    /**
     * returns list containing agenda of all meetings
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getAgendaList() {
        ArrayList<String> agendaList = new ArrayList<String>();
        agendaList.add(getSelectedMeeting().getAgenda());
        return agendaList;
    }

    /**
     * this method is used to get a list of employee names for employees who are not invited to a particular meeting 
     */
    public List<String> getEmpNameIdList() {
        List<EmployeeEntity> employeeList = new ArrayList<EmployeeEntity>(EmployeeService.getCurrentInstance()
                .getEmployeeList());
        List<String> uninvitedEmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListIterator<EmployeeEntity> empIter = employeeList.listIterator();
        ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (empIter.hasNext()) {
            idList.add(empIter.next().getEmpId());
        }

        MeetingEntity meeting = getSelectedMeeting();
        List<EmployeeEntity> employees = meeting.getEmployees();
        if(employees!=null){
        ListIterator<EmployeeEntity> invitedIter = employees.listIterator();
        ArrayList<Integer> invitedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (invitedIter.hasNext()) {
            invitedIds.add(invitedIter.next().getEmpId());
        }
        idList.removeAll(invitedIds);
        }
        EmployeeEntity emp;
        ListIterator<Integer> idIter = idList.listIterator();
        while (idIter.hasNext()) {
            int id = idIter.next();
            emp = EmployeeService.getCurrentInstance().getEmployeeForId(id);
            uninvitedEmpList.add(emp.getFirstName() + " " + emp.getLastName() + " (" + emp.getEmpId() + ")");
        }
        return uninvitedEmpList;
    }

    /**
     * this method adds employees to a meeting
     * @return
     */
    public String addEmpToMeeting() {
        MeetingEntity meeting = MeetingService.getCurrentInstance().getMeetingFromAgenda(
                getSelectedMeeting().getAgenda());
        for (int i = 0; i < empIdsInMeeting.length; i++) {
            String id = null;
            id = empIdsInMeeting[i].substring(empIdsInMeeting[i].lastIndexOf("(") + 1,
                    empIdsInMeeting[i].lastIndexOf(")"));
            int empId = Integer.parseInt(id);
            meeting.getEmployees().add(EmployeeService.getCurrentInstance().getEmployeeForId(empId));
        }

        MeetingService.getCurrentInstance().addMeeting(meeting);
        return "empAddedToMeeting";
    }





    /**
     * this method removes employee from a meeting
     * @return
     */
    public void deleteEmployee(){
        List<EmployeeEntity>inviteEmployees=getSelectedMeeting().getEmployees();
        EmployeeEntity emp=getDeletableEmployee();
        inviteEmployees.remove(emp);
    }

    public Integer getSelectedMeetId() {
        return selectedMeetId;
    }

    public void setSelectedMeetId(Integer selectedMeetId) {
        this.selectedMeetId = selectedMeetId;
        setSelectedMeeting(MeetingService.getCurrentInstance().getMeetingForId(selectedMeetId));
    }

    public MeetingEntity getSelectedMeeting() {
        return selectedMeeting;
    }

    public void setSelectedMeeting(MeetingEntity selectedMeeting) {
        this.selectedMeeting = selectedMeeting;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getRequestMap() {
        return requestMap;
    }

    public void setRequestMap(Map<String, Object> requestMap) {
        this.requestMap = requestMap;
    }

    public Date getMeetingTime() {
        return meetingTime;
    }

    public void setMeetingTime(Date meetingTime) {
        this.meetingTime = meetingTime;
    }

    public String getAgenda() {
        return agenda;
    }

    public void setAgenda(String agenda) {
        this.agenda = agenda;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public int getMeetingId() {
        return this.meetingId;
    }

    public List<EmployeeEntity> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public String[] getEmpIdsInMeeting() {
        return empIdsInMeeting;
    }

    public void setEmpIdsInMeeting(String[] empIdsInMeeting) {
        this.empIdsInMeeting = empIdsInMeeting;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<EmployeeEntity> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public String getSelectedAgenda() {
        return selectedAgenda;
    }

    public void setSelectedAgenda(String selectedAgenda) {
        this.selectedAgenda = selectedAgenda;
    }



    public void setTimeOrder(SortOrder timeOrder) {
        this.timeOrder = timeOrder;
    }

    public int getDeleteEmpId() {
        return deleteEmpId;
    }

    public void setDeleteEmpId(int deleteEmpId) {
        this.deleteEmpId = deleteEmpId;
        setDeletableEmployee(EmployeeService.getCurrentInstance().getEmployeeForId(deleteEmpId));
    }

    public EmployeeEntity getDeletableEmployee() {
        return deletableEmployee;
    }

    public void setDeletableEmployee(EmployeeEntity deletableEmployee) {
        this.deletableEmployee = deletableEmployee;
    }


}
```

Please help .

Comment: Where is the removeEmp() javascript in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably related to JSF overriding your custom onclick.
The work-around would be to use onmousedown instead of onclick, with the potential caveat described here:
http://blogs.oracle.com/jtb/entry/jsf_h_commandlink_and_onclick

Answer (score -2):

i had the same problem few days ago, changing the return to true may work for you.